# How do I file for an LLC in Florida?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, limited-liability-company, florida

I own multiple mobile apps and currently live in NYC. Each app is under it's own LLC single-member which is me. However, I am sick and tired of paying a leg and an arm in NYC taxes. Local + State taxes add up to an extra 100k taxes I will be paying this year. I believe this is seriously unfair especially since I do not occupy an actual location to conduct business and all my business can be done through an internet connection from anywhere in the world.

My questions.

1. Do I have to be a resident of Florida to set up an LLC there?
2. If I have to be a resident of Florida to form an LLC, how long do I have to live in Florida to be considered a resident?
3. Can I set up virtual mailboxes in Florida to receive mail for the LLC's?
4. I will be needing to set up around 6 LLC's and all will make 100k+ or more per year. Will I have any issues setting up multiple LLC's?
5. Will the business ownership show if someone Google's my name?

Thanks. Really look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to be a resident of Florida to set up an LLC there?

No

> Can I set up virtual mailboxes in Florida to receive mail for the LLC's?

Probably, but you still have to have a registered agent

> I will be needing to set up around 6 LLC's and all will make 100k+ or more per year. Will I have any issues setting up multiple LLC's?

Why would you have issues? Set up as many as you want.

> Will the business ownership show if someone Google's my name?

Probably, it's a public record.

---

To avoid the New York taxes, it's not the LLC that needs to be in Florida, it's **you** that need to be in Florida. It doesn't matter where the LLC is, as long as **you** are in New York - you're going to pay NY taxes.

If you're making 100k/year, how is having a set of LLCs costs you **extra** 100k? Check your numbers.

Comment: Each LLC makes 100k or more per year and state+local taxes add up to a combined 100k per year through all the LLCs and since I am a single member on all of them, I pay taxes on my sum earned.

Comment: @SunnyJoe that has nothing to do with LLCs really. **You** are paying the taxes on the sum earned.